# Version conflict (google-services plugin)

Tags: android, gradle

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
>   available at
>   https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
>   or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 15.0.2.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {


    compileSdkVersion 26
//    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.android"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        versionCode 9
        versionName '3.6'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        debug {
            //     signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        // exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.picasso/picasso/pom.xml'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':slidingmenu_libs')
    implementation project(':sqlite_helper')
    implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.2.5.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpcore-4.2.4.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.2.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/lib-autonotifyviewpager.jar')
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:1.0.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.eftimoff:android-viewpager-transformers:1.0.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.24.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.joanzapata.pdfview:android-pdfview:1.0.4@aar'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Did you updated google-service plugin? it is located in build.gradle(Project) under dependecies section, the last version is `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0' // google-services plugin
`

Comment: @E.Abdel it's working after updating

Comment: Nice, please post an answer and accept it to help other people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the google-service plugin to `'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'`

However, its always better to have same version among the same library file to prevent any project sync crash.

Example,

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.2'
```

Comment: @Kapi Bryant thank you for answer,i have already resolved,see the comment

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it happens when you updating google play services or firebase dependencies, you might solve it by updating the play service plugin in your `build.gradle` (project) file:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    }
}
```